# Load on start up throwing 404

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

This is my servlet,when ever i try to run the dynamic web project in my eclipse,it throws 404 error,is anything wrong with my web.xml configuration.
The servlet class in web.xml is leading to respective servlet (crtl + mouse click).What could possibly be wrong with my web.xml configuration,pls help!

```
package java_barchartservlet;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

//import java_barchart.ImageDemo;


import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartUtilities;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.category.DefaultCategoryDataset;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class BarChartExample
 */

public class BarChartExample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public void init()
        {
            //initialize( or add a log statement to debug)
        }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {




        try {

            /* Step - 1: Define the data for the bar chart  */
            DefaultCategoryDataset my_bar_chart_dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(34, "WMOS", "2013");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(45, "DOM", "2013");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(45, "TLM", "2013");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(22, "WMOS", "2014");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(12, "DOM", "2014");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(12, "TLM", "2014");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(56, "WMOS", "2015");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(98, "DOM", "2015");
            my_bar_chart_dataset.addValue(98, "TLM", "2015");


            /* Step -2:Define the JFreeChart object to create bar chart */
           JFreeChart BarChartObject=ChartFactory.createBarChart("productVsYear - Bar Chart","Year","Modifications",my_bar_chart_dataset,PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,true,true,false);                

             /* Step -3: Write the output as PNG file with bar chart information */                
             int width=640; /* Width of the image */
             int height=480; /* Height of the image */ 



             File BarChart=new File("C:/Users/seramaiah/Pictures/output_chart.png");              
             ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(BarChart,BarChartObject,width,height);


             FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/seramaiah/Pictures/output_chart.png");  //read the file

             response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=test.txt");

            //new ImageDemo("C:/Users/seramaiah/Pictures/output_chart.png");

     }
     catch (Exception i)
     {
         System.out.println(i);
     }
 }




    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>  
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>java_barchartservlet.BarChartExample</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>   
</web-app>
```

Comment: Which book/tutorial/resource did you use to learn creating servlets and registering them in web.xml? I'd like to contact the author about a severe instruction mistake (if it wasn't actually yourself who ignored or misread the resource, of course).

Comment: <servlet-mapping> part is not present in web.xml which used to specify path/pattern for which registered servlet is called

Comment: javatpoint,any ways why?

Comment: what do i specify in servlet mapping,i mean i dont have an url to specify?

Comment: This one? http://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-tutorial Albeit heavily outdated (we have annotations since a decade) and not official (Oracle Java EE itself has a tutorial too), it seems OK. This section explains web.xml registration: http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-a-servlet-using-tomcat-server#servletstep4 How exactly is it unclear to you?

Comment: Balus,the problem am currently facing is,i have a servlet class and i want it to load as soon as the server starts,i cannot use servlet mapping since am not calling this servlet in jsp or html through action attribute.How do i load it on server start up,whats possibly going wrong ?

Comment: What is your default page when you run your web app. You haven't even specified welcome file. What are you trying to access whey you run your app? No servlet mapping, no welcome file. Isn't 404 obvious.

Answer (score 0):

> when ever i try to run the dynamic web project in my eclipse,it throws
>   404 error,is anything wrong with my web.xml configuration.

What is your default page when you run your web app. You haven't even specified welcome file. What are you trying to access when you run your app? No servlet mapping, no welcome file. Isn't 404 obvious.

Update your web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app>  
        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>java_barchartservlet.BarChartExample</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
       </servlet>

       <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/fireServlet</servlet-class>
       <servlet-mapping>


    <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>  
    </web-app>
```

You can send the request for your servlet from index.jsp

OR

directly map the servlet to the context path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app>  
            <servlet>
              <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
              <servlet-class>java_barchartservlet.BarChartExample</servlet-class>
              <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
           </servlet>

           <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/</servlet-class>
           <servlet-mapping>
       </web-app>
```